# vba conditional formatting to columns

Tags: vba, excel, conditional-formatting

i am a newbie in VBA, so i come across with several issues.

I have a dataset that looks like this:

[image: data]

I have to compare column A with columns B,C,D,E and F and then color the fonts of the cells in columns B:F under these conditions:

1. If cells in column A are equal with the cells in columns B:F, paint their font orange.
2. If cells in column A are higher than the cells in columns B:F, paint their font red.
3. If cells in column A are lower than the cells in columns B:F, paint their font green.
4. If the absolute difference between column A and the rest columns (B:F) is less than 1, paint their font orange.

I have tried to write a simple macro and all conditions are met except the 4th.

Here is my attempt.

---

```
Sub ConditionalFormating()
Dim i, j, a As Double
    a = 0.99
    i = 2
    j = 2

    For j = 1 To 6     
    For i = 2 To 10

     ActiveSheet.Cells(i, j).Select


   If ActiveSheet.Cells(i, j) - ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1) >= a Then

    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = RGB(255, 156, 0)
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
   End If


     If ActiveSheet.Cells(i, j) - ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1) <= a Then

    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = RGB(255, 156, 0)
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
   End If


   If ActiveSheet.Cells(i, j) > ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1) Then

    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
   End If



    If ActiveSheet.Cells(i, j) < ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1) Then

    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
   End If

   Next
    Next
End Sub
```

---

Could anyone help me? I cannot understand why the 4th condition is not met when all others are.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: By the way, the Pattern property refers to an old formatting mode where diagonal lines, diamond shapes, dots, etc. are drawn on the cell. So, maybe you should write just Selection.Color=RGB(255,156,0)

Comment: And you don't need to Select the cells, its more efficient if you just write With ActiveSheet.Cells(i,j)

Comment: Do you need to do it in vba? Normal conditionnal formating seems the way to do it for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To color the font, you have to use the Font property of Range, like: Selection.Font.Color=RGB(255,128,0).

Answer (score 0):

you could try this (commented) code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub ConditionalFormating()
    Dim cell As Range, cell2 As Range, dataRng As Range
    Dim colOrange As Long, colRed As Long, colGreen As Long, col As Long

    colOrange = RGB(255, 156, 0)
    colRed = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    colGreen = RGB(0, 255, 0)

    With Worksheets("CF") '<--| reference the relevant worksheet (change "CF" to your actual worksheet name)
        Set dataRng = Intersect(.Columns("B:F"), .UsedRange)
        For Each cell In .Range("A2", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants) '<-- loop through its column "A" not empty cells from row 1 down to last not empty one
            If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Intersect(dataRng, cell.EntireRow)) > 0 Then ' if current row has data
                For Each cell2 In Intersect(dataRng, cell.EntireRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants) ' loop through current column "A" cell row not empty cells
                    Select Case True '<-- check the current datum against the following conditions
                        Case cell2.Value = cell.Value Or Abs(cell.Value - cell2.Value) < 1 'if current datum equals corresponding value in column "A" or their absolute difference is lower than 1
                            col = colOrange
                        Case cell2.Value < cell.Value 'if current datum is lower then corresponding value in column "A"
                            col = colRed
                        Case cell2.Value > cell.Value  'if current datum is higher then corresponding value in column "A"
                            col = colGreen
                    End Select
                    With cell2.Interior
                        .Pattern = xlSolid
                        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                        .Color = col
                        .TintAndShade = 0
                        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
                    End With
                Next cell2
            End If
        Next cell
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! Really appreciate it! The code works really fine when my data starts from column A, but it seems that when there are others columns before col A, the 4th condition is still not met. Any idea why this happens??

Comment: In fact my column A (named C_O_P) should ALWAYS be in the 14th column (that is column N)!

Comment: You are welcome. As per this site rules 1) If I fulfilled your _original_ question (dealing with _"column A with columns B,C,D,E and F"_) you should mark my answer as accepted by clicking on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in. 2) In case of new issues you should first try and solve them by yourself working on the given code. should you not succeed then make a new post showing your coding efforts